# Caching Serializers, fails to cache associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I am trying to implement some caching with Active Model Serializer; this is my serializer.

```
class ServiceFieldSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :meta_description, :content, :practitioner_term, :avatar, :slug
  has_many :services
  embed :id, include: true

  cached
  delegate :cache_key, to: :object

  def services
    object.services.published
  end

  def avatar
    object.image_url :avatar if object.image.present?
  end
end
```

The service serializer

```
class ServiceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :meta_description, :content, :practitioner_term, :avatar, :slug
  has_one :service_field
  embed :id

  cached
  delegate :cache_key, to: :object

  def avatar
    object.image_url :avatar if object.image.present?
  end
end
```

Output "y ServiceSerializer.new(Service.first)"

```
object: !ruby/ActiveRecord:Service
  attributes:
    id: 4
    name: ADHD Coaching
    description: Bliv klogere på hvorfor du har det damp i hovede
    service_field_id: 2
    created_at: 2014-02-18 08:08:41.755177000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-04-29 08:30:44.111671000 Z
    content: tihihi
    image:
    published: true
    meta_description:
    slug: adhd-coaching
    practitioner_term:
```

My problem is, when i have the cached call, my json response looks like this.

```
service_fields: []->
0: {id:2, name:Coaching, description:Det bliver du glad for, meta_description:, content:,…}
1: {id:1, name:Massage, description:Massage er godt for krop og alt i hele verden., meta_description:null,…}
2: {id:3, name:Terapi, description:Noget med nogle møder, meta_description:null,…}
```

As you can see the associated services is missing, if i remove the caching from the serializer the services is there.

What am i doing wrong?

Rails version: 4.0.5

AMS version: 0.8.1

Comment: Did you try to clear your cache and just to be sure you're not getting old cached values somehow?

Comment: I restarted memcached multiple times yes, and held i eye to the log, yes :).

Comment: Not to be nagging, but any chance you're not even using memcached while testing? Maybe you're using the default file store somehow?

Comment: The cache is set to delli 'config.cache_store = :dalli_store', with perform_caching. As i wrote, i can see in the log that the cache in being written too, and that it resets when restart memcached. :-)

Comment: @MartinElvar serializer ServiceSerializer present?

Comment: @Vakiliy I have added it to the thread :)

Comment: @MartinElvar hm, show result ServiceSerializer.new(Service.first).to_json

Comment: @MartinElvar, ok, but show generated json after to_json, because gem stored cache only if call to_json or serializable_array methods

Comment: @MartinElvar,  create simple app same like you, its work properly. 2.1.2 :120 > ServiceFieldSerializer.new(ServiceField.first).to_json
Dalli::Server#connect 127.0.0.1:11211
Cache generate: service_field_serializer/service_fields/1-20140617152721586926000/to-json
Cache read: ..
Cache write: ...
 => "{\"services\":[{\"id\":2,...],\"service_field\":{\"id\" ...\"service_ids\":[2,3]}}"

Comment: It's the exact same response i get with to_json, but in json.

Comment: @MartinElvar what app version you are using?

Comment: @Vakiliy Wops, i have added the version numbers to the bottom. :)

Comment: @MartinElvar, hm, likewise work properly

Answer (score 2):

you are not doing anything wrong... in fact I spent more than a week to figure why this is not working and what i found was that AMS caching doesn't work with sideloaded relations...

but if you want to continue figuring out what is wrong... then have a look at [this AMS fork](https://github.com/asknative/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable) we made to solve this specific issue using the informations found in AMS caching issues...

one thing to note... by using this gem we were able to reduce the amount of time spent querying collections... but it nearly have no effect on loading 1 object... only collections... and we were able to reduce some collections time from 75% to 10% I know that reducing only 10% isn't that good... thats why we are moving to [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) now (3 days ago)... and to be honest with you I didn't figure out how it's caching works

#### EDIT

about jbuilder and caching times... using jbuilder with the appropriate partial caching (fragment caching) we were able to get response times of about 40ms when the collection was not cached and about 15ms when it was cached... the response times before caching was about 130ms (cause fragment caching doesn't invalidate the whole object and it's relations... only the changed parts)... so i recommend using jbuilder with a presenter layer ( like [Draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) ) and [jbuilder multi cache](https://github.com/joshblour/jbuilder_cache_multi) for better collection caching

Comment: I was afraid of that, and for the time being the AMS repo seems rather quiet. Out of curiosity, how much of a performance gaing do you get with JBuilder compared to AMS? Because as my application gets more complicated, i am facing some nasty loadtimes, even with eager loading.

Comment: I will give this question some more time, before accepting your answer, might be one out there who happens to know a fix :).

Comment: true... that's why we moved to JBuilder in every new project we had in asknative :D... also i didn't add this answer to get the bounty or anything... i added this to get a feedback about my conclusion that AMS is really slow specially with sideloaded relations...
I'm not in a position to judge the performance of JBuilder... in fact i'm striving to grasp it and have a working thing up and running... and my experience with it is less than a week but it seems promising

Comment: I can see you are using Emberjs aswell, so same story :). For my almost 1.5 sec loads, i ended up creating a preview serializer for the heavy models; which i use on my index actions, which yields me about 60% performance gain, ofc this won't help if you need to display everything. Currently we don't have the time to switch the json serializer to jbuilder, but i will look into it if AMS gets completely out of hand. :)

Comment: just try the fork... and you should be on the path of solving the issue ... and please if you found anything you can add just PR to the fork cause we are in great need for this to be correctly done using AMS

Comment: @MartinElvar i edited the answer adding stats about the gain we got using jbuilder... i don't have a reference to AMS cause we didn't use it first then switched... we just ignored it... and we think it was the correct call :D

Answer (score 1):

So i while google, i found this post http://homeonrails.com/2014/03/fast-rails-api/ which seems to solve the problem, by fragment caching it manually.

```
@services_fields = ServiceField.includes(:services)
json = Rails.cache.fetch 'test' do
  ActiveModel::Serializer.build_json(self, @services_fields, {}).to_json
end

respond_with json
```

Which renders the correct JSON.

Feel free to post alternatives.